# problema al eliminar un elemento de recyclerview con firebase

Tags: firebase, android-fragment, recyclerview, cardview

Tengo el siguiente problema. Al intentar eliminar un elemento de un recyclerview que toma sus datos de firebase; en la base de datos el elemento se elimina correctamente; pero en el recyclerview no se actualiza correctamente. Interpreté que el problema era que no estaba implementando correctamente "notifyDataSetChanged()", pero aparte de ello es que tras la lista se añade nuevamente los elementos almacenados en la bbdd. Pensé por tanto que la solución sería refrescar el recyclerview de forma que esté se vuelva a cargar con los datos actualizados, pero no encuentro la forma de realizarlo. Os agradecería alguna orientación. Dejo el código del bind en el que tengo alojado el evento

```
   fun bind(datos: ArrayAsuntosPropios) = with(itemView) {
        if (datos.yearAP == yearActual && email == datos.email) {
            fechaAP.text = datos.fechaAP
            if (datos.diaDescanso) {
                yearAP.text = "Descanso"
                yearAP.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            } else {
                yearAP.text = "Trabajado"
                yearAP.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
            }
        }
        itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
            val fechaSeleccionada = datos.fechaAP
            val store: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            val diasASuntoPropiosColeccion: CollectionReference = store.collection("diasAsuntosPropios")
            diasASuntoPropiosColeccion
                .whereEqualTo("fechaAP", fechaSeleccionada).whereEqualTo("email", email).limit(1)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    for (document in documents) {
                        val idDocumento = document.id
                        diasASuntoPropiosColeccion.document(idDocumento).delete()
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "error al encontrar el documento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        })
    }
```

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo donde haces el notifyDataSetChanged() quizas no estas actualizando correctamente los datos de la lista en el adapter

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. En realidad el código notifyDataSetChanged() lo tenía colocada a continuación de la línea "diasASuntoPropiosColeccion.document(idDocumento).delete()" Me apareció en rojo, señal de que no estaba bien implantado; lo eliminé simplemente para probar que se borraba bien en la BBDD y estudiar luego como implantarlo, pero entonces me llevé la sorpresa de que se añadian nuevamente los datos al comunicar firebase la modificar. A partir de ahí consideré que la solución no estaba en aplicar notifyDataSetChanged(), sino en refrescar el frament Nuevamente gracias por contestar

Comment: entiendo, por lo que me comentas el problema debe estar en el momento de leer los datos de firebase, el ValueEventListener donde recuperas los datos debe estar agregando los datos que trae en un array que despues se lo pasa al adapter, pero ese array no se debe estar limpiando antes de agregarse nuevos datos, por eso se deben ver repetidos. Esto es solo una suposicion, tendria que ver ese listener para estar seguro

Comment: Creo que es un error básico mio. He tratado de borrar desde el Bind del adapter. Funcionó para la bbdd y por eso crei que estaba bien. Creo que lo que debo de hacer es llamar a una función en el fragment desde donde se haga la eliminación, y posiblemente así sí podré aplicar notifyDataSetChanged() que no podía usar en el propio Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto. En el bind del adapter:

```
fun bind(datos: ArrayAsuntosPropios, listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    if (datos.yearAP == yearActual && email == datos.email) {
        itemView.fechaAP.text = datos.fechaAP
        ....
    }
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val fechaSeleccionada = datos.fechaAP
        val store: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val diasASuntoPropiosColeccion: CollectionReference = store.collection("diasAsuntosPropios")
        diasASuntoPropiosColeccion
            .whereEqualTo("fechaAP", fechaSeleccionada).whereEqualTo("email", email).limit(1)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    val idDocumento = document.id
                    diasASuntoPropiosColeccion.document(idDocumento).delete()
                }
            }
        listener.onItemClick(datos, adapterPosition) }
}
```

}

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(movie: ArrayAsuntosPropios, position: Int)
}
```

Luego en el fragment

```
private fun borrar(position: Int) {
    messageListFiltrado.clear()
}
```

Limpio el array y cuando llega la entrada desde firebase, se actualiza.
Lo que me sorprende es que esperaba utilizar adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() pero al final no es necesario. Es decir esperaba tener que notificar al adapter que la lista se ha vaciado, para limpiar el recyclerview y que se recargara; pero ha funcionado sin actualizar